# An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid URL - Angular v17.0.0

Tags: angular, typescript

new angular project version 17 with enabled SSR and PreRender, when I run the `ng build` command it returns the following error.

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid URL
See "C:\Users\hjort\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-DWGMVS\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

And in the log file

```
[error] TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
at new URL (node:internal/url:778:13)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:821:16)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1034:11)
at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:832:28)
at Hooks.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:277:30)
at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:35)
at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:220:38)
at ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:307:34)
at Hooks.register (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:138:51)
```

The generated `app.routes.ts` was empty so I have tried added a route, still same issue.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
 {
    title: 'Titel här',
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent
 }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `ng new --ssr` has both the `discoverRoutes` and the `routesFile` set to true, but as there are no routes in the `routes.txt` file (as none is generated) it throws an error. By just setting the `discoverRoutes` in the `angular.json` to true it works

```
 {
    "projects": {
    "my-app": {
    "architect": {
         "build": {
           "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
           "options": {
             "prerender": {
               "discoverRoutes": true
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```